# Excluding terms inside parentheses using regex

Tags: python, regex

I only want to capture the words that are capitalized that are not in parentheses:

```
Reggie (Reginald) Potter -> Reggie Potter
```

I am using this regex:

```
test = re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s\(.*?\))?(?=\s[A-Z])(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+)', 'Reggie (Reginald) Potter')
```

I get this back:

```
Reggie (Reginald) Potter
```

I thought since this is non capturing:

```
(?:\s\(.*?\))
```

I wouldn't get back anything inside of the parentheses

Comment: What about `Foo (Bar Baz) Quz (Qaz (Maz) Paz) Raz`?

Comment: I am assuming that there will only be a single set of parens after the first word (like a nickname)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the words you want to avoid are directly adjacent to parentheses, you could use [negative look-behinds and look-aheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match the ones that are not in parentheses:

```
(?<!\()\b([A-Z][a-z]+)\b(?!\))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simpler regex plus a list comprehension:

```
all_words = re.findall(r'(\(?\b[A-Z][a-z]+\b\)?)', 'Reggie (Reginald) Potter')
good_matches = [word for word in all_words if len(word) > 0 and not (word[0] == '(' and word[-1] == ')')]
```

Now `good_matches` is `['Reggie', 'Potter']`, as expected.

Comment: Would match `Bar` in `fooBar`.

Comment: @Qtax Ah - I forgot my customary word boundary characters.  Fixed.